# How to get the current Windows user's *network* identity, not their interactive log-on identity?

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, windows-identity

**Question**:

What is the .NET (or p/invoke to an unmanaged Windows API) method call to get the current process's **network identity** that is used to connect to SSPI-authenticated network services, such as SQL Server?

---

The specific use-case I have in mind is where one can work on a non-domain-joined machine and use `runas /noprofile /netonly /USER:DOMAIN\username` to launch a process which uses that `DOMAIN\username` identity for network authentication instead of their local `MACHINE\username` logged-on identity.

I want the method call that gives me the `DOMAIN\username` identity passed to `RUNAS` here.

Thanks!

---

To be clear, I am *NOT* looking for the method call to get the current user's locally logged on identity (which may be different than the network identity). This *excludes* `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` and `Environment.UserName` and probably `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` from being accepted answers. I will downvote any answer that incorrectly indicates any of these to be the solution, unless I am shown to be wrong here of course. :)

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  Are you trying to get the user's name from _inside_ the launched process?

Comment: Yes. This code should be executed with the process being `runas`ed

Comment: It *probably* excludes them? Have you or haven't you tried them? And your last bit sounds a little confrontational for a question where you're asking for others' help. If you've tried things (as it sounds like you have), you should of course disclose that to help make solving your problem easier, but there's no need to go that far, IMO.

Comment: It was not meant to be confrontational, merely a yield sign to prevent someone from needlessly wasting their time answering if all they had to offer was something which I had already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints the user (in the form "user@domain") for outbound connections.  It's C++.

```
CredHandle credHandle;
TimeStamp timeStamp;
SECURITY_STATUS status = AcquireCredentialsHandle(0, L"Negotiate", SECPKG_CRED_OUTBOUND, 0, 0, 0, 0, &credHandle, &timeStamp);
if (status == SEC_E_OK)
{
    SecPkgCredentials_Names names;
    status = QueryCredentialsAttributes(&credHandle, SECPKG_CRED_ATTR_NAMES, &names);
    if (status == SEC_E_OK)
    {
        wprintf(L"%s\n", names.sUserName);
        status = FreeContextBuffer(names.sUserName);
    }
    status = FreeCredentialsHandle(&credHandle);
}
```

Some other information:  I guess `runas` is using CreateProcessWithLogonW with the LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY flag.  This creates a new logon session based on the existing logon session, with the net credentials hidden inside it.  GetTokenInformation and LsaGetLogonSessionData return information about the original user, not the network user.  The one bit of Windows that must know about the network user is SSPI, so that it can send the user name and domain to the remote server.  Hence the code above.